# Coloring a square

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, elementary-set-theory

Let $V$ be the set of all four vertices of a square , and $\{1,2,3\}$ the set of all possible colours. We call a coloring of a square , a function $ f: V\rightarrow$  $\{1,2,3\}$ a coloring of a square, and $F_H=\{$$ f: V\rightarrow$ $\{1,2,3\}$$\}$

Also , we say that $f \thicksim g$ if there exists a permutation $\psi : V \rightarrow V $ , such that $ f \circ \psi = g$ , which preserves the sides of the square , namely , if ab is a side , $\psi (a) \psi(b)$ is also a side.

I need to come up with the number of elements in $F_H/\thicksim$ and the number of elements in each of the classes .
I have found all elements in $F_H/\thicksim$ , according to the number of colours and the order we use them , but I cannot find the number of elements in each of those sets.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, if we had a colouring with four distinct colours, then there would be $|D_4| = 8$ equivalent colourings. In our actual cases, some of these will give identical colourings, so the number will reduce, but not increase: the cardinality of the equivalence class of a colouring $f$ is precisely the cardinality of the set $\{\sigma(f) | \sigma \in D_4 \}$ of images of your colouring under $D_4$, so we can just check each of those eight and count which are distinct.

Going through the options:

If our colouring is constant, then clearly its equivalence class has only one element.

If our colouring has three vertices of one colour, and the fourth difference, then its equivalence class has four elements (indexed by where the different colour is).

If our colouring has two vertices each of two different colours, and the same colours are adjacent, then there are again four equivalent colourings (indexed by which side has both vertices one of the colours).

If our colouring has two vertices of each of two different colours, and the same colours are not adjacent, then there are only two equivalent colourings (indexed by which diagonal has both vertices one of the colours).

If our colouring has two vertices of one colour, and one of each other colour, and the two same-colour vertices are adjacent, then all images of our colouring under $D_4$ are distinct, so there are eight equivalent colourings.

If our colouring has two vertices of one colour, and one of each other colour, and the two same-colour vertices are not adjacent, then there are four distinct images (fix which diagonal is same-coloured (2), then swap the positions of the other two colours).